# Getting current servo angle with GPIO

Tags: gpio, servo

Without using Occidentalis (which might not even work that way), is there any way to get the current angle of a servo? I know it has a potentiometer, I just have no idea how to go about getting that info from it (if you can at all)... I am wanting to hook this up to a deadbolt and have an app that you can control it with, but if you manually unlock it with a key, I would like it to update the app saying that the door is now unlocked.

Comment: A traditional RC servo does not provide any position reporting outside of the case.  With analysis of the control circuit inside you could potentially interpret the utilized signals, or you could replace the control circuit with an MCU & H-Bridge replacement that talks bidirectional I2C or something like that instead of PWM.  However, it might be simplest of all to add an additional switch or magnetic/optical sensor to tell you the state of the latch.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Yeah, Chris, please add this as an answer so I can mark it?